# Grails: Inheritance, how to access everything including subclasses

Tags: inheritance, grails

I'm having a structure like

Animal

- Cat
- Dog
- Mouse

Usually I want to use each class separately but, for an example, on my main screen I want an table showing all animals + a search.
Table:

```
Luna - Cat - 2 -  - ...
Miranda - Dog - 10 - 09109009 - ...
...
```

How can I handle this kind of requirement?

**Already tried:**
animalList -> results in empty list

Comment: Polymorphism: `Animal.list()`.

Comment: I just realized I might need to clarify a little more. I'm using dynamic scaffolding, which provides me with several methods which are automatically mapped to the requested data. e.g. list(). List usually returns the list of this type but in case of animals it doesn't show anything though cat, mouse, dog are animals. I expected to see everything.

Comment: I just made a fascinating discovery - it seem to be an issue unrelated to inheritance. If I change <f:table collection="${animalList}" /> to <f:table collection="${catList}" /> it shows me everything. I didn't change anything in the controller.

Comment: The model variable name is generated based on the type of the first element in the collection.  If `catList` is working that means that the first element in the `List` is a `Cat`.  You probably don't really want to rely on that because it won't work if the first element is ever anything other than a `Cat`.

Comment: The code that generates the name is at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/005de08fbfa84c50529dab3b869db33807505f70/grails-plugin-rest/src/main/groovy/org/grails/plugins/web/rest/render/html/DefaultHtmlRenderer.groovy#L114.

Comment: Oh holy moly - that makes sense. Dirty, but makes sense. So basically I gotta do it manually. :(
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution by @Jeff Scott Brown (see comments):
The model variable name is generated **based on the type of the first element in the collection**. If catList is working that means that the first element in the List is a Cat. You probably don't really want to rely on that because it won't work if the first element is ever anything other than a Cat.

To resolve this issue I stopped relying on dynamic scaffolding and created a table myself.